# Unity Hololens2 move a Ragdoll by force

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, interaction, ragdoll

right now I am starting to code on a Hololens game in Unity. I want to move some body parts of a character but with physics. 
For example I move the hand of the character to his mouth, then I let go and the hand will fall to a normal position. To get this work, I tried first without physics and the result (with objectmaipulator and nearinteractiongrabbable script) was this:
[pic of ugly hand][1]
So to get in the physics I read about the ragdoll wizard, but when I use him. The object manipulator wont work at all. 
Can someone help me? Or recommend some good tutorial, because I could not find anything... 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I cannot see the screenshot and maybe it is not uploaded properly. Would you refine the question and provide more details? A general answer for this is to ensure the Unity Gameobject you want to manipulate has both Collider (usually Capsule or Box) and Objectmaipulator components attached.